# How to set or add a frontend user group of an existing and new user using extbase on TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I need to migrate users from an other app into TYPO3 and are not able to set the user group of new users. Updating existing users and adding the group works.

Here is my code.

```php
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 */
protected $userRepository;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository
 */
protected $userGroupRepository;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 */
protected $persistenceManager;

...

$this->userGroup = $this->userGroupRepository->findOneByTitle('My desired group');
$this->userGroupStorage = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
$this->userGroupStorage->attach($this->userGroup);

$user = $this->userRepository->findOneByForeignId($id);
if ($user) {
    $this->updateUserData($user);
    $this->userRepository->update($user);
} else {
    $user = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser();
    $this->updateUserData($user);
    $this->userRepository->add($user);
}
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

...

private function updateUserData($user)
{
    $user->setPid($this->pid);
    $user->setFirstName($this->firstName);
    ...
    
    // I use either this or the other line, not both at the same time!
    
    // works on new and existing users but never gets persisted
    $user->setUsergroup($this->userGroupStorage);
    
    // throws error on new user but gets persisted on existing users
    $user->addUsergroup($this->userGroup);
}
```

Why is the UserGroupStorage not sored in the database? My workaround would be creating the user persist it, reload it from the database and add the user group. But that's no good practice.

Comment: Oehm, which error is thrown? 
You are attaching `$group` to `$userGroupStorage`, but two lines above, the group is assigned to `$this->userGroup`- `$group` has no value. `$user->setUsergroup($this->userGroupStorage);`will persist an unchanged storage.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Oh, you're right. I made a mistake when simplifying the code for this post. Thanks for pointing it out.  
The error message when using `addUsergroup()` on a new user object is: *Call to a member function attach() on null. Error thrown in file /app/public/typo3_src/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php in line 202.* This is because the new user's usergroup is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution (or workaround).

```php
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 */
protected $userRepository;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository
 */
protected $userGroupRepository;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 */
protected $persistenceManager;

...

$this->userGroup = $this->userGroupRepository->findOneByTitle('My desired group');
$user = $this->userRepository->findOneByForeignId($id);

...

if ($user) {
    $this->updateUserData($user);
    $this->userRepository->update($user);
} else {
    $user = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser();
    $this->updateUserData($user);
    $this->userRepository->add($user);
}
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

...

private function updateUserData($user)
{
    $user->setPid($this->pid);
    $user->setFirstName($this->firstName);
    ...
    
    if ($user->getUsergroup() === null) {
        $user->setUsergroup(new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage());
    }
    $user->addUsergroup($this->userGroup);
}
```

This way I don't get an error message for new users and the changes are always stored in the database.

Comment: Strange... Normally `usergroup` should always be an ObjectStorage. It's initialized with the object: https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/extbase/blob/9.5/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php#L132

Comment: Maybe it's a bug of the older TYPO3 version that is fixed meanwhile.
But what's strange too is that `setUsergroup()` with a filled ObjectStorage does not store the user group in the database.